# Empty /boot/efi directory

Tags: uefi, refind

Currently running 14.10.
When I first installed `rEFind` I could access the `refind.conf` in `/boot/efi/EFI/refind`. Then after rebooting, `/boot/efi` becomes an empty directory and the only was I found I can get access to `refind.conf` is by re-installing `refind`.
I'm sure this isn't the correct way to modify `refind.conf`
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing your `/etc/fstab` file to automatically mount the ESP. It will look something like this:

```
UUID=E231-242F            /boot/efi            vfat    utf8,fmask=0133  0  1
```

You'll need to change the `UUID` value from `E231-242F` to whatever it is on your system. Type `sudo blkid | grep fat` to see a list of possibilities. With any luck there'll be just one, but you may need to check two or more to figure out the right one. (You can mount a partition temporarily with the `mount` command, as in `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`, then check its contents and unmount it with `umount /mnt` -- note there's just one `n` in `umount`; that's not a typo.)

There are numerous variants on the options (`utf8,fmask=0133` in this example). Don't worry about them too much, although some have security implications.

Comment: That worked well! Thanks for the detailed reply Rod.

Comment: I should also add, thanks for a fantastic piece of software.